# Zimbra SOAP create account

Tags: php, rest, soap, zimbra

I want to create Zimbra user account with **SOAP API** and can't get it to work - it's strange because I can get the **AuthToken** and can even view info of the accounts that are already created (via admin panel) with request `GetAccountRequest`, but the creation of the account does not work.

Here's my code for the AuthToken (POST) request:

```
Header: Content-Type: application/soap+xml

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header xmlns="urn:zimbra">
    <context></context>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AuthRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin" password="myPassword"> 
        <account by="adminName">my.name@mydomain.com</account> 
    </AuthRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And this works, I get the Auth token back.

Next I try to create new user account with this (POST) request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
    <context>
<authToken> 0_69cd602eef3cf46bb488b02c6a173da698d17bdb_69643blablaTherestofmyauthtoken</authToken>
</context>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
     <CreateAccountRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin" name="john.doe@mydomain.com" password="john123!"> 
        <a n="givenName">John</a>
        <a n="sn">Doe</a>
        <a n="displayName">John Doe</a>
    </CreateAccountRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And this is the response I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [soap:Code] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [soap:Value] => soap:Sender
        )

    [soap:Reason] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [soap:Text] => no valid authtoken present
        )

    [soap:Detail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Error] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Code] => service.AUTH_REQUIRED
                    [Trace] => btpool0-3022://zimbra.mydomain.com:7071/service/admin/soap:1449756733826:bc04a0eab6d6c7ec:SoapEngine368
                )

        )

)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: for normal user auth and sending mail what is the port? is it 9071?

Answer (score 3):

So I figured it out - when you make an AuthToken request, you receive a cookie with the AuthToken value and when you try to create a new user account, you have to send that cookie back in the header section like this:

```
Cookie: ZM_ADMIN_AUTH_TOKEN=0_69cd602eef3cf46bb488b02c6a173da698d17bdb_69643blablaTherestofmyauthtoken
```

The whole request must look like this:

```
$request= array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => array(
            'Content-Type: application/soap+xml',
            'Cookie: ZM_ADMIN_AUTH_TOKEN=0_69cd602eef3cf46bb488b02c6a173da698d17bdb_69643blablaTherestofmyauthtoken',
        ),
        'timeout'  => 20, 
        'ignore_errors' => true,  
        'content'  => '
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <soap:Header xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
                    <context>
                        <authToken> 0_69cd602eef3cf46bb488b02c6a173da698d17bdb_69643blablaTherestofmyauthtoken</authToken>
                    </context>
                </soap:Header>
                <soap:Body>
                    <CreateAccountRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin" name="john.doe@mydomain.com" password="john123!"> 
                        <a n="givenName">John</a>
                        <a n="sn">Doe</a>
                        <a n="displayName">John Doe</a>
                    </CreateAccountRequest>
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
        ',
    ),
);
```

It is explained in the [documentation](https://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.0/soapapi-zimbra-doc/api-reference/index.html) the Admin Authorization token is required, but it doesn't says anywhere you have to send that back via cookie in the request header.

Answer (score 0):

Zimbra provides two methods to obtain the AuthToken:

1. User Token

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:zimbraAccount">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <urn:AuthRequest>
            <urn:account by="name">${email}</urn:account>
            <urn:password>${password}</urn:password>
        </urn:AuthRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

2. Admin Token

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <AuthRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
            <account by="name">${email}</account>
            <password>${password}</password>
        </AuthRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note: Both token payloads in the requests are similar, but the namespace changes to urn:zimbraAdmin for the Admin Token.

When working with the Admin API, it is essential to obtain the AdminToken. The [documentation](https://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.8.15/api-reference/index.html) specifies the required namespace in the header, typically labeled as Service:

- Namespace: "urn:zimbraAdmin"

Whenever the namespace is "urn:zimbraAdmin," the Admin Token must be used.

To create an account, use the following example:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
    <soap:Header/>
    <context xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
        <authToken>${authAdminToken}</authToken>
    </context>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateAccountRequest name="${email}" password="${password}">
        </CreateAccountRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```